# Zariski closure of the set of maximal ideals

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, zariski-topology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $ \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is the set of prime ideals with Zariski toplogy.
The set of maximal ideals is denoted by $X= \operatorname{mSpec}(R)$.
We consider $\overline{X}$, which is the Zariski closure of $X$.
Can you describe necessary and sufficient conditions for $X$ to satisfy  $\overline{X}=X$ ?

Comment: There is the notion of Jacobson space : a space is Jacobson if every closed subset is the closure of the set of closed points in it. Then a space $X=\operatorname{Spec}R$ is Jacobson iff $R$ is a Jacobson ring.

Comment: So you want the set of maximal ideals to be closed? At least this set is dense iff the nilradical is the intersection of the maximal ideals, i.e, the jacobson radical is equal to the nilradical.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is Noetherian, then $X$ is closed iff $R$ has only finitely many maximal ideals.  The reverse implication is trivial; for the forward implication, note that if $X$ is closed then it is Spec of a quotient of $R$ which is zero-dimensional and Noetherian, but a zero-dimensional Noetherian ring is Artinian and has only finitely many maximal ideals.